# Unable to read the count of some words from file of size ~2GB with Perl

Tags: perl, shell

I have written a Perl program which will match certain words in a log file and store the results in a database. The problem is this program works fine with a small file but doesn't work with file size ~2GB. Is it size or program need to be changed?

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

# load module
use DBI;

open( FILE, "/root/temp.log" ) or die "Unable to open logfile:$!\n";
$count_start   = 0;
$count_interim = 0;
$count_stop    = 0;

while (<FILE>) {
  @test = <FILE>;
  foreach $line (@test) {

    if ( $line =~ m/server start/ ) {

      #print "yes\n";
      $count_start++;
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ m/server interim-update/ ) {
      $count_stop++;
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ m/server stop/ ) {
      $count_interim++;
    }

  }
  print "$count_start\n";
  print "$count_stop\n";
  print "$count_interim\n";
  $now_string = strftime "%b %e %H:%M:%S", localtime;
  print $now_string;

  # connect
  my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:Pg:dbname=postgres;host=localhost",
    "postgres", "postgres", { 'RaiseError' => 1 } );

  # execute INSERT query
  my $rows = $dbh->do(
"insert into radcount (acc,bcc,dcc) Values  ('$count_start','$count_stop','$count_interim')"
  );

  print "$rows row(s) affected\n";

  # clean up
  $dbh->disconnect();

}

close(LOG);
```

Comment: You should always `use strict` and `use warnings`. Although it would not have helped find your problem here, it still helps to find mistakes. Also consider always using [DBI's placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Valu‌​es). That way you avoid problems with quoting of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few comments about your program.

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declare variables using `my` at their point of first use
- *Always* use lexical filehandles and the three-parameter form of `open`, and *always* check the status of an open call
- You are opening the file using filehandle `FILE`, but closing `LOG`
- Your `while` statement reads the first line of the file and throws it away
- `@test = <FILE>` attempts to read *all* of the rest of the file into the array. This is what is causing your problem
- You should connect to the database *once* and use the same database handle for the rest of the code
- You should use `prepare` your statement with *placeholders* and pass the actual values with `execute`
- You are incrementing `$count_stop` for an `interim-update` record and `$count_interim` for a `stop` record
- The core module `Time::Piece` provides a `strftime` method without the bloat of `POSIX`

Here is a modification of your program to show these ideas. I have not set up a log file and database to test it but it looks fine to me and does compile.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use DBI;

open my $log, '<', '/root/temp.log' or die "Unable to open log file: $!";

my ($count_start, $count_interim, $count_stop) = (0, 0, 0);

while (<$log>) {

  if ( /server start/ ) {
    $count_start++;
  }
  elsif ( /server interim-update/ ) {
    $count_interim++;
  }
  elsif ( /server stop/ ) {
    $count_stop++;
  }
}

print <<END;
Start:   $count_start
Interim: $count_interim
Stop:    $count_stop
END

print localtime->strftime("%b %e %H:%M:%S"), "\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:Pg:dbname=postgres;host=localhost", "postgres", "postgres",
    { 'RaiseError' => 1 } );

my $insert = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO radcount (acc, bcc, dcc) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
my $rows = $insert->execute($count_start, $count_stop, $count_interim);

printf "%d %s affected\n", $rows, $rows == 1 ? 'row' : 'rows';
```

Comment: Thanks a tonnn @Borodin..It did solve my problem and able to read ~3GB file..but it is somewht slow..will look into tweaking...Thanks a lot....

Comment: @maa: This shouldn't take more than about 30 seconds or so to run, and there isn't much you can do with the code to speed it up. Is your file on a network drive? That would explain the slowness - expect a few minutes to read through the file in that case - and you could speed things up by copying the data to a local drive beforehand.

Comment: :@Borodin:Yepp it took 21s to execute.My file is on local drive.The problem is,the file is zipped(temp.log.gz).do i need to unzip using perl and use the above program.Plz guide.

Comment: @maa: I see you have switched your choice of answer. That's no problem but please explain why so that I can learn from you

Answer (score 5):

There's a few things here - first off I'd recommend changing to three arg open for your file handle - reasoning [here](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/04/three-arg-open-migrating-to-modern-perl.html)

```
open( my $fileHandle, '<', '/root/temp.log' ) or die "blah" ;
```

Secondly you're reading the whole file into an array - with a large file this will eat a lot of ram.  Instead read it line by line and process it:

```
while(<$fileHandle>){
    #contents of your foreach loop
}
```

Comment: Also, `use strict` and `use warnings`!

Comment: and `use autodie` !  Yeah I definitely should have mentioned those, thanks for picking it up

Comment: oh and `use DateTime::TimeZone` would probably be a good idea as well I guess

Comment: I'm not sure about `autodie`. `DateTime`... well. It works like it is. I was thinking more along the lines of being on conscientious. Another thing that's not too great is the absence of [`DBI`-placeholders](search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI/DBI.pm#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values). I'd consider that bad style as well. But we should really put that in the comments of the question, not your answer, which is good.

Comment: there may be some potential for shenanigans (depending on what they're expecting from the data they are storing) when the next leap day|second or DST hit without using a time module which can handle that sort of fluff though..  You've certainly made the most sensible comments here - bung them on the question!

Comment: @nickisfat: `$!` is a much better example die string than `"blah"`, and even shorter